# Filtrar conteúdo por Categoria com select + Bug em filtro Javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um filtro dentro de um arquivo JSON que ao digitar ele vai filtrando e deixando só o que você vai escrevendo, problema é que se eu ia apagando o que está no campo de busca ele não continua filtrando e volta ao normal quando apago tudo. O outro ponto é que eu queria saber se dá pra iterar nesse código um filtro por categoria com um select, deixarei o código abaixo

**CÓDIGO DO FILTRO+JSON**

```js
window.onload=function(){
 data = { person: [ 
  { 
  author: "Nobtaka Nukui",
  title: "Want people to use your product? Use it yourself",
  url: "http://www.medium.com",
  category: "Product Design",
  comments: "4 coments",
  created_at: "43 minutos atrás",
  classcor: "corUm",
  foto: '<img src="img/ft-3.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem1">',
  upvotes: 11 },
   {
  author: "Danil Ishutin",
  title: "wont Size Idea: px at Root, rem for Components, em for Text Elements",
  url: "http://www.css-tricks.com",
  category: "UX Theory",
  comments: "7 coments",
  created_at: "5 minutos atrás",
  classcor: "corDois",
  foto: '<img src="img/ft-2.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
  upvotes: 9},
  {
  author: "Kenny Schrub",
  title: "Some things cant be prototyped",
  url: "http://www.mika.el",
  category: "Opinion",
  comments:'25 coments',
  created_at: '7 minutos atrás',
  classcor: 'corTres',
  foto: '<img src="img/ft-2.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
  isOwner: true,
  upvotes: 4 
   },
  {
  author: "Jacky Mao",
  title: "How to prototype without any tools",
  url: "http://www.jackymao.wix",
  category: "Opinion",
  comments: '0 coments',
  classcor: 'corTres',
  foto: '<img src="img/ft-1.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
  upvotes: 4
   },
   
  {
  author: "Christopher Alesund",
  title: "Case study: Redesigning the Folyo landing page",
  url: "http://www.medium.com",
  category: "Case Study",
  comments: '0 coments',
  classcor: 'corQuatro',
  foto: '<img src="img/ft-1.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
  created_at: '7 hours ago',
  upvotes: 3
   },
   {
  author: "Pasha Biceps",
  title: "Don't let bad process or structure kill great interfaces",
  url: "http://www.medium.com",
  category: 'Product Design',
  comments: '0 coments',
  classcor: 'corUm',
  foto: '<img src="img/ft-3.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
  created_at: '2 days ago',
  isOwner: true,
  upvotes: 2
   }
  
  ]};
  
data.person.forEach(function(p){ 
  
  var post = "<section><span><a href='#'></a>"+p.upvotes+"</span><div><a href="+p.url+">"+p.url+"</a><h1>"+p.title+"</h1><nav><a  href='#' id='bt-category' class="+ p.classcor +" title="+ p.category +">"+p.category+"</a><p>"+p.foto+"<a href='#' title="+p.author+">"+p.author+"</a>"+p.created_at+"<a  href='#' class='coments'>"+p.comments+"</a></p></nav></div></section>";
    
  document.querySelector('#dados').innerHTML += post;
  
  
  });
  
 $('#filtro').keyup(function () {
  var yourtext = $(this).val();
  if (yourtext.length > 0) {
   var abc = $("section").filter(function () {
    var str = $(this).text();
    var re = new RegExp(yourtext, "i");
    var result = re.test(str);
    if (!result) {
     return $(this);
    }
   }).hide();
  } else {
   $("section").show();
  }
 });

}
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body { width:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column; height:100vh; align-items:center;}
:focus{ outline: none; } 
UL{ list-style:none; }
A{ text-decoration:none; overflow:hidden; }

/*** HEADER ***/

HEADER{ width:100%; position:relative; flex-shrink:0; flex-direction:column; padding:26px 0 30px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f0; margin-bottom:60px; }

/*** CONTEÚDO ***/

main{ width:900px; display:flex; align-self:center; flex-direction:column;  flex:1 0 auto; }
main SECTION{ width:100%; display:flex; margin-bottom:48px; }
main SECTION SPAN{ width:46px; height:77px; display:flex; flex-direction:column; background:url(img/bg-upvote.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; text-align: center;font: normal bold 25px/25px arial; margin-right:21px; }
main SECTION SPAN A{ width:46px; height:32px; float:left; color:#363636; margin-bottom:12px; }
main SECTION DIV A{ font: normal bold 15px/15px arial; color:#cbcbcb; }
main SECTION DIV A:HOVER{ text-decoration:underline; }
main SECTION DIV H1{ font:normal normal 23px/25px arial; color:#383535; padding:5px 0; }
main SECTION DIV NAV{ display:flex; }
main SECTION DIV NAV #bt-category{ height:24px; display:flex; font: normal normal 15px/15px arial; color:#fff; justify-content: center;align-items: center;border-radius: 10px;padding: 0 10px;}
main SECTION DIV NAV #bt-category:HOVER{ text-decoration:none; }
main SECTION DIV NAV .corUm{ background-color:#00e2ad; }
main SECTION DIV NAV .corDois{ background-color:#00bbff; }
main SECTION DIV NAV .corTres{ background-color:#4271d6; }
main SECTION DIV NAV .corQuatro{ background-color:#f4973c; }
main SECTION DIV NAV P{ font: normal normal 15px/22px arial; color:#6e6c6c; border-left:1px solid #c7c7c7; margin-left:12px; padding-left:14px; }
main SECTION DIV NAV P A{ color:#e3472f; text-decoration:underline; margin-left:5px; margin:0 10px; }
main SECTION DIV NAV P .coments{ background:url(img/balao.png) no-repeat 0 3px; padding-left:20px; }
main SECTION DIV NAV P IMG{ position:relative; top:5px; }

/*** RODAPÉ ***/

FOOTER{ width:900px; height:54px; display:flex; flex-shrink:0; alig-self:center; background-color:#0CC;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header><input id="filtro" type="text" placeholder="Busca Rápida"></header>
<main id="dados" ></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Qual a estrutura desse "*JSON*" ?

Comment: vou postar o código inteiro

Comment: @wmsouza pronto só executar ali